# Adjective to replace "small" in "small part"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for the replacement for the adjective "small" as in "small part", e.g:

> I am dedicating the small part of my article to....

which would not over-emphasize the fact of being small, but at the same time keeping it clear that it is not the major and most significant part.

Comment: How about "minor"? It's the opposite of major.

Comment: How is it a small part? Is it an abstract or a section? In that case, how about using those words instead?

Comment: I voted to close this question because, without more context, we cannot provide an answer that's any better than what you might find by looking in a general reference such as a thesaurus entry for [small](http://thesaurus.com/browse/small), or alternatively for a word that describes the [abstract (noun)](http://thesaurus.com/browse/abstract) or [section](http://thesaurus.com/browse/section) of your article. (You can still edit your closed question to provide more information and it may then be reopened if it is clearer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

> modest: limited in size or scope.